# How can I do this recursive search in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.CharArrayReader;

public class Program2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String filename = args[0]; //reads command line argument 1 as filename
        Scanner File = new Scanner(new File(filename)); //reads filename into                          program,and opens it for analysis
        File.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.seperator"));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); //creates an array list to store chars to transfer for reading from the file
        while (File.hasNext()){
            list.add(File.next());
        }
        File.close();
        char[][] array1 = new char[10][20];
        for (int i =0; i < list.size(); i++){
            array1[i] = list.get(i).toCharArray();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File is not found: " + e.getMessage() );//catches and sends out an error message
    }
}

static int CharSearch(char[][] array1, char a, char b, char c){
    for (int i =0 ; i < array1.length; i++){
        for (int j =0; j < array1.length; j++){
            while (a == 'A'){
                return 1;
```

Hi all, so I have to make a program that reads in a file that is a 10x20 grid. The grid has letters A, B, C. All chars, in random order. What I need to do, is find a searching algorithm that checks for "groupings" of these letters.

Much like this much smaller version:

```
AABBACCA

CCABACBA

CCAAAABB

AAAACCCC
```

So see how there are 3 C groups, 2 B groups, and 3 A groups? (the groups can only be touching horizontally or vertically, not diagonally.)

I have to count that. I tried it, as can be seen on the bottom. 
Also, I wanted to also make sure that the rest of my code makes sense and won't just pfft on me.

Thank you :)

Comment: How about do a connected component labeling, then for each component see if they are 'A', 'B' or 'C', and add the corresponding counter

Comment: This is a classical simplified [Connected-component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) problem that can be solved efficiently using a, [union-find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Either than that I'm not sure how to help you, what have you tried and what are you looking for here? I don't think that we should implement code for homework (or you will not learn anything from it); so go ahead and try to tackle the problem, if you hit an specific wall open a new question and we will help you.

Comment: Not sure why you would need a union find structure for this. Simple graph traversal will do.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was just having issues translating what I have on my head onto the IDE. I just needed a little push in the right direction.